# Separate white image from dark background

Tags: adobe-illustrator, background-removal

I'm creating a t-shirt design and need to know how to combine all the white shapes that make this image and separate it from any dark green. The white image will eventually be printed on a dark green t-shirt as shown in the template. If you open the file you can see that the image was created with a combination of white and dark green shapes. I would like the white part that's visible to be the only image in this file.

Here's the link to the illustrator file: http://www.lendtmusik.com/NWBandAlumniT-Shirtversion2.ai

Comment: I think this should answer your question: [**How can I separate colors by layer in Illustrator?**](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/17944/8708)

Comment: Or this one: [**Simple Spot Color Separations for Screen Printing**](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/18486/8708)

Answer (score 1):

- delete (or lock) t-shirt shape.
- Select artwork
- Object > Expand Appearance
- Object > Expand
- Pathfinder > Merge
- Select a white shape
- Select > Same > Fill & Stroke
- Edit > Copy
- Select All, Delete
- Edit > Paste

You are left with only the needed shapes.

[image: animation]

[image: cats]

Comment: **Important note:** [Hobo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hobo_%28typeface%29) should be replaced in this document before going to print.

Comment: @plainclothes Why? (Other than for aesthetic reasons, I dislike Hobo aesthetically.) It's not live text and would present no issue with reproduction.

Comment: Just trying to help improve the World for future generations. (It's a joke)

Comment: Ahh.. that's what I thought. And I agree, Hobo, Comic Sans, Zapfino, Zapf Chancery should all NEVER be used :).

Comment: We have a responsibility to the progress of mankind!